# Clicking input using JS

Tags: javascript, automation

I have a scenario where I need to automate the profile update functionality using JavaScript (JS). Currently, I am facing an issue. When I click on the edit button, a model pops up with input fields and a submit button. However, the submit button is initially disabled. It works fine when I manually fill in all the required inputs, as the submit button becomes enabled.

The problem arises when I try to automate this process using JS. I am able to successfully click on the edit button and replace the input values by selecting their respective IDs and changing their values. However, despite the changes being visible on the screen, the submit button remains disabled. Additionally, when I click on any input field, the values that were changed using JS disappear from the input fields.

I have attempted to use mimic user interaction, but it has not resolved the issue for me.

I have tried these solutions so far

**Tried #1**

`var email = "test@gmail.com"; var nemail = document.querySelector("#new-email"); nemail.value = email; nemail.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))`

**Tried #1**

`var inputElement = document.getElementById("new-email");

// Move the cursor to the input field
inputElement.focus();

// Simulate a click event on the input field
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
view: window,
bubbles: true,
cancelable: true
});
inputElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
inputElement.value = 'test@gmail.com'`

Comment: do they listen for key, focus, or blur events? Try triggering those.

Comment: Are you running this through the browser console/userscript or using a browser driver like puppeteer?

Comment: By the way, instead of manually dispatching the mouseevent why not `inputElement.click()`?

Comment: I am running the code in the browser console. and already tried ```inputElement.click()``` but it not working either